# Insert a formula if cell is cleared

Tags: google-sheets

This is a pretty specific problem I have, but is it possible to assign a formula to a cell, which would always be assigned to the cell, even if I overwrite it manually and then clear it?

So for example I would have a cell A2 with formula =SUM(B2:C2), which would show 8. If I then overwrite it with 4, it naturally would show 4 in the A2. Now the behaviour I would like to have is if I clear the cell A2, the formula =SUM(B2:C2) would again be automatically entered there, resulting A2 showing 8.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a Google Apps Script [simple onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite):

> The **onEdit(e)** trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet.

On the Sheets editor, click `Tools > Script editor`. Once in the script editor, copy the following function and save the project:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const notation = "A2";
  if (range.getA1Notation() === notation && range.getValue() === "") {
    range.setFormula("=SUM(B2:C2)");
  }
}
```

Using the [Edit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), this function checks that:

- The edited cell is `A2`.
- The edited cell is empty.